# Accessing object properties within a callback execution

Tags: php, class, oop, callback

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class RandomNumber{
  public $number;

  function __construct($range,$callback){
    $this->number = rand(0,$range);
    $callback();
  }
}

$rnd = new RandomNumber(9,function(){
  echo "Line 11: ".$rnd->number."\n";    // Not working: empty variable
  echo "Line 12: ".$number."\n";         // Not working: empty variable
  echo "Line 13: ".$this->number."\n";   // Not working: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context on line 13
});
echo "Line 15: ".$rnd->number."\n";      // Working: echoed random number
```

So I'm trying to access the property (`number`) of the newly created object. And I can not guess how to do it properly. I have read some PHP documentation and tried to search Google for the solution but I missed the thing or I used wrong keywords for searching. I'd be happy if you will point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's barely possible, because the things are happening one after the another, as well as the function is not aware of the outside world. In your case `$rnd` is declared outside the function as well as it's not already initialized (it will be after the whole line is executed)

And yes, you are not able to use `$this`, but you can pass `$this` in order to inject the newly created object.

```
class RandomNumber{
    public $number;

    function __construct($range,$callback){
        $this->number = rand(0,$range);
        $callback($this);
    }
}

$rnd = new RandomNumber(9,function($obj){
    echo "Line 11: ".$obj->number."\n";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the function outside of the scope of the class, inside of it it works just fine.
And `$rnd` cant work inside of it, as it is not yet filled, this will happen after the constructor did its work.

This works:

```
class RandomNumber{
  public $number;

  function __construct($range,$callback){
    $this->number = rand(0,$range);
    $callback($this);
    $call2 = function(){
            echo "Line 7 : " .$this->number."\n"; // Works
    };
    $call2();
  }
  public function callback($callback){
    $callback();
  }
}

$rnd = new RandomNumber(9,function($rnd){
  echo "Line 15: ".$rnd->number."\n"; // Works
});
$rnd->callback(function() use ($rnd) {
  echo "Line 19: ".$rnd->number."\n"; // Works
});
```

Comment: Seems to me like a big overkill :)

Comment: ;) I was curious what you can do with Closures, as I use them not very often.